# Como exibir contagem de comentários do Facebook na página de posts do Admin do Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, comentários

Sei que para exibir comentários no frontend do blog é só adicionar `<fb:comments-count href=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>></fb:comments-count>` em qualquer lugar do tema.

No entanto, preciso exibir a contagem de comentários **dentro da listagem de Posts no Admin do Wordpress**, de preferência sem plugins, via `functions.php`. Melhor ainda se puder combinar as contagens de comentários padrão do Wordpress e do Facebook.

Já "googlei" em inglês e em português tentando encontrar uma forma de fazer isso, mas não encontrei. Se alguém souber e puder ajudar eu agradeço. Valeu!

Comment: Você tem a referência/documentação desse `<fb:comments-count>`? Isso funciona sem plugin algum?

Answer (score 1):

Use o código do próprio Facebook

```
<fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count>
```

usando o Post->ID

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments